# Enable line numbers on the left side of jed editor by default

Tags: editor

I can toggle line number from Buffers menu. But I want it to be enabled by default.I am asking about the line numbers on the left side, not the one in the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Please insert below code in your .jedrc file.

```
public define global_mode_hook (hook_name)
{
    set_line_number_mode (1);
}
```

;-)

Comment: Somehow, your code not working, would you verify your code?

Answer (score 0):

opt's answer is correct, but the code should be at the bottom of your .jedrc. There should be a line that says something like:

```
%  Hooks:  read jed/doc/hooks.sl for more information
```